# How to throw variable result of an array on flutter from class to class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to transport function result of json process from class to another class.
This is the json I rendered:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi"
  }
]
```

Result of method is showing when I tried to print inside that method, but not printed on destination class. These is my codes:

Source class:

```dart
class DataNews {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String body;

  DataNews({this.id, this.title, this.body});

  factory DataNews.fromJson(json) {
    return DataNews(id: json['id'].toString(), title: json['title'], body: json['body']);
  }
}

getData() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    List data = json.decode(response.body);
    final items = (data).map((i) => new DataNews.fromJson(i));
    print('Satu');
    print(items.elementAt(1).id);
    print(items.elementAt(1).title);
    print(items.elementAt(1).body);
    print('Dua');
    return items;
}
```

Destionation class:

```dart
class News extends StatefulWidget {  
  @override
  _NewsState createState() => _NewsState(post: getData());
}

class _NewsState extends State<News> {
  Iterable<dynamic> post;
  _NewsState({Key key, this.post});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Text(post.elementAt(0).title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to show one of the result on Container. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your method `getData()` doesn't return an `Iterable`, it returns a `Future<Iterable>`, but it would be better if it returned a `Future<List>`, instead. Please, annotate the types you're using, it'll make your life much easier.

```dart
Future<List<DataNews>> getData() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  List data = json.decode(response.body);
  List<DataNews> items = data.map((i) => DataNews.fromJson(i)).toList();
  return items;
}
```

Second, you should not pass any data to `_NewsState`. Either the data comes from the parent `Widget` and gets stored in `News` or you fetch the data inside `_NewsState` itself. [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) can help you to display the content that comes from a `Future`.

```dart
class News extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewsState createState() => _NewsState();
}

class _NewsState extends State<News> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(), // Fetch the data
        builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // If your List got fetched, them show each DataNews using a ListView
            List<DataNews> newsList = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: newsList.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text(newsList[index].title),
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            // If you have no data, show a progress indicator
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It works now. But I have question, why getData return Future data type? and I'm very curious what happening on AsyncSnapshot process. Could you show me how this future printing result with standard loop so I can understand that comprehensively? Thank you.

Comment: You get a `Future` every time you are doing working with asynchronous code. `AsyncSnapshot` holds your data when your `Future` manages to complete the data fetching. You can read about async here: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That help me a lot. I will learn future further. Thank you so much.